# How to limit the installation of app to just iPhone X?

Tags: swift, plist, iphone-x

Is there a way to limit the installation of my app just to iPhone X? I developed a game that is taking advantages of True Depth System and I don’t want it to be downloadable on other iPhone’s model.

I seen from the .plist that under required capabilities there is nothing specific to iPhone X only.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that, but if you can, I recommend you don't try that. You are heavily restricting your app audience, and there may be another alternative than **needing** True-Depth. Take an AR game for example, usually there is a mode to switch **off** AR so you can use the app normally without restricting users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I require a user to have a True Depth camera to download my app from the App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083462/can-i-require-a-user-to-have-a-true-depth-camera-to-download-my-app-from-the-app)

Comment: Reading through the conflicting answer on the dup link, my thoughts look accurate - no. At least not if you want to market your app through the App Store. I'd do three things: (1) Add code to check for the device and/or capabilities and have *something* that will work without it, then (2) put on your App Store page how "much better" (read: more enjoyable, better experience, etc.) your app is with the capability of TDS, and (3) maybe use the "free trial" IAP to gently let those without an iPhone X (or in another month, newer models) know how limited things are on their iPhone 8 Plus downward.