# Augmented Reality for iOS and swift front facing camera applications

Tags: iphone, swift, avfoundation, augmented-reality, arkit

I am developing an app that needs to use the front facing camera of the iPhone for Augmented Reality experience using swift. I have tried to use the ARKit, but the front facing camera made by the ARKit is only supported for iPhone X.

So, which frameworks or libraries that I can use with swift to develop apps that has AR experience especially fro front facing camera, other than ARKit?

Answer (score 4):

#### ARKit 6.0

TrueDepth front-facing camera of iPhone (models from X to 15) gives you Depth channel at frame rate of 60 fps and Image front-facing camera gives you RGB channels at 60 fps too. However, if you do not need ARFaceTracking in your app, you can use AVFoundation or Apple Vision frameworks instead. Nonetheless, using an iPhone with a TrueDepth camera makes developing FaceTracking apps much easier.

TrueDepth sensor's infrared emitter projects a pattern of 30,000 dots onto the user’s face. Those dots are then captured by a dedicated IR camera for analysis. Additionally, an ambient light sensor helps the system set a light level.

[image]

If you don't have a TrueDepth sensor in your gadget (iPhone SE, iPhone 6s, iPhone 7 and iPhone 8 don't have) you cannot use such features as `Animoji`, `Face ID`, or `Depth Occlusion` features.

In ARKit for iOS, a configuration that tracks the movement and expressions of the user’s face with the TrueDepth camera, runs an object of `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` class. ARKit allows you simultaneously track a surrounding environment with back camera and track your face with the help of front camera – you can track up to 3 faces at a time.

Here's two scenarios of how to setup your AR config.

---

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

if configuration.supportsUserFaceTracking {
    configuration.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true
}
session.run(configuration)

func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors where anchor is ARFaceAnchor {
        // you code here...
    }
}
```

---

```
let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()

if configuration.supportsWorldTracking {
    configuration.worldTrackingEnabled = true
}
session.run(configuration)

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    let transform = frame.camera.transform
    // you code here...
}
```

Comment: But yet still there are applications that uses ARKit for AR apps development. One of the apps I have found working on iPhone 7 for both frontal and rear camera is called Bemo. So, I am sure that there is a way to use AR with the front camera. Even if I know that the facial recognition for AR experience is only available for iPhone X.

Comment: AppStore rejects apps with third-party frameworks and libraries (like Bemo). But if you're using The Enterprise Apple Developer  Program (what provides resources for developing and distributing proprietary, in-house iOS apps to employees) – you're maybe welcome!

Comment: Bemo app uses only ARKit, as noted in the description, and it is in the AppStore

Comment: Sometimes AppStore may miss such an app due to inattention. But after some time App with a third-party framework will be deleted from AppStore (there are countless examples of this). Have you seen a code of `Bemo` app?

Comment: Apple locked a front camera (for developers of ARKit for iPhone 6s/7/8) for a definite purpose, didn't it ??? It's a pure marketing of iPhone X.

Comment: Read this SO post for detailed info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083462/can-i-require-a-user-to-have-a-true-depth-camera-to-download-my-app-from-the-app

Answer (score 4):

ARKit isn't the only way possible to create "AR" experiences on iOS, nor is it the only way that Apple permits creating "AR" in the App Store.

If you define "front-facing-camera AR" as something like "uses front camera, detects faces, allows placing virtual 2D/3D content overlays that appear to stay attached to the face", there are any number of technologies one could use. Apps like Snapchat have been doing this kind of "AR" since before ARKit existed, using technology they've either developed in-house or licensed from third parties. How you do it and how well it works depends on the technology you use. ARKit guarantees a certain precision of results by requiring a front-facing depth camera.

It's entirely possible to develop an app that uses ARKit for face tracking on TrueDepth devices and a different technology for other devices. For example, looking only at what you can do "out of the box" with Apple's SDK, there's the [Vision](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) framework, which locates and tracks faces in 2D. There's probably a few third party libraries out there, too... or you could go looking through academic journals, since face detection/tracking is a pretty active area of computer vision research.

Comment: Can you mention of other AR frameworks or technologies that I can use for iOS development?