# Uploading App fully dependent on Arkit face tracking

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, arkit

I have developed a face filter app that uses ARKIt and FaceTrackingConfiguration to detect face mesh and apply the texture on it. The app is completed and now I want to upload it to the app store. As my app is fully dependent on FaceTrackingConfiguration and it only works with true depth camera how I can restrict my app on app store to be available on devices with a true depth camera. I know we can restrict device by adding arkit key in uiRequiredDeviceCapabilities but it won't solve my issue as iphone 7 and many devices support arkit but doesn't support true depth

For now I am thinking of adding the following UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities on info.plist

```
   <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>arkit</string>
    <string>iphone-ipad-minimum-performance-a12</string>
    <string>front-facing-camera</string>
</array>
```

By Adding "iphone-ipad-minimum-performance-a12" it will remove the support of iPhone X and add support for iPhone se(2nd gen) which should not be supported. ios 14 add face tracking for non true depth camera which have a12+ chips so I guess iphone se will be supported on ios 14.

I am looking for better solution.

here is the video of my app.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUF9-9jfAxw

Comment: Duplicate - see this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083462/can-i-require-a-user-to-have-a-true-depth-camera-to-download-my-app-from-the-app

Comment: My question is different. here I am looking for best solutions as I already know that we cant ignore other devices which doesnt have truedepth camera.

Comment: Where did you see this? -> "ios 14 add face tracking for non true depth camera which have a12+ chips"